Chrome measure FPS incorrect
Following code，if delete el.innerText = "FPS: " + fps; the result will be wrong.
let lastTime = performance.now();
let lastFrameTime = performance.now();
let frame = 0;
let fps = 0;

const loop = function () {
  const now = performance.now();
  const fs = now - lastFrameTime;
  lastFrameTime = now;
  frame++;
  if (now > 1000 + lastTime) {
    fps = Math.round((frame * 1000) / (now - lastTime));
    frame = 0;
    lastTime = now;
    //If delete this statement, the stats is incorrect
    el.innerText = "FPS: " + fps;
    console.log(fps);
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
loop();

Image here
Reproduce

Open Console (Click right-top icon "Chrome DevTools for the preview")
Click switch button in the  top-right of the preview. (The FPS of the page and the FPS in the Console are the same)
Delete code el.innerText = "FPS: " + fps;
Repeat 1 and 2 （The FPS of the Console is wrong.）

Click here to view demo.

Is this causing you a specific problem? If your issue is that the FPS is being reported incorrectly is causing knock-on effects with some game logic, then this is why you shouldn't be relying on FPS for anything.

Your code works identically in all browsers I tried it in - by the way, did you know that the callback function to requestAnimationFrame takes an argument that may be helpful to you

^^^ I mean the code you posted here, not the code in the demo - yeah, that code is really odd in Chrome

I want to monitor the FPS of the animation, but the data is incorrect.
